# normal subgroup in $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is $\{(1),(1,3)\}$ a normal subgroup in $S_3$? I know that a normal subgroup means that the left cosets are equal to the right cosets.

Comment: You should test this by hand; there aren't too many multiplications to perform.

Comment: @Gamamal answer is correct, and it uses your definition of 'normality' in a n equivalen (but slightly different) way. You say that $H\leq G$ is normal if, and only if, for all $x\in G$ we have $xH=Hx$. With only few lines of proof you can show that $H$ is normal in $G$ if, and only if, $x^{-1}Hx=H$.

Answer (score 1):

$(12)^{-1}(13)(12)=(12)(13)(12)=(23)$ which is not in the subgroup. Hence the subgroup is not normal.

The subgroup $\{e,(123),(132)\}$ is normal however. You should test it by hand. I did not do this however because there is a theorem that tells you if a subgroup has exactly half of the elements then it is normal.

Comment: What theorem is that?

Comment: I don't think it has a name but it can be found as an excercise in dummit foote/ The proof is not too hard. Remember a subgroup is normal if $gH = Hg$ for all $g\in G$. It is easy to verify this is the case when the set has half the elements.